# How to solve Class not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader in Unix

Tags: java, unix

I am trying to run a java class from a .jar file in unix environment, but i am getting the following error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SystemBootstrap
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SystemBootstrap not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[], 
 parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
```

The command i am using to run the class is

```
 java -cp BatchFramework.jar  SystemBootstrap dnqLtrBatch DEV1
```

SystemBootstrap  is the class to be called , i am  not able to solve this.And i am very new to unix.

Comment: Only one solution: You have to supply the missing class.  Find the JAR that contains the missing class and make it available at runtime.

Comment: @duffymo the jar BatchFramework contains the class SystemBootstrap , i have checked

Comment: Then the BatchFramework is not packaged correctly.  It's not in the CLASSPATH.  The JVM cannot find it at runtime.  If this is an executable JAR,  I think it means you either don't have a manifest to tell the JAR where to find its dependencies OR the dependent JARs are not packaged into a "fat" executable JAR.

Comment: @duffymo ok so the CLASSPATH is correct  ?

Comment: obviously not.  It doesn't include your BatchFramework JAR with the class that cannot be found.

Comment: @duffymo ok so i should rebuild the BatchFramework jar ?

Comment: Rebuild it in a different way.  Simply repeating the same behavior that gave you the JAR you have won't change anything.  It's easy if you use Maven: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven